# AngularDart with AngularJS libraries

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Recently I've started to learn Dart language (purely for fun) and yesterday I read CodeLabs for AngularDart. I went throught all 10 chapters and I've felt in love. Till now I wrote many angularJS apps so I know what are principles of this framework.
But my question is - **is there any way to combine AngularJS libraries like RestAngular or Angular-Translate in AngularDart applications? Or even directives like Angular-material or AngularUI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular needs full control of the DOM tree it sees as the app (`ng-app`) It should be possible to use Angular.js and Angular.dart to use non-overlapping parts of the DOM and run one subtree with Angular.dart and another with Angular.js.

It might be possible to call Angular.js services from Angular.dart using dart-js-interop but besides that I don't think they can work together.

Comment: Thanks :) I've read already a bit about using JS in Dart and I know everything :)